# How to run an exe file with input arguments from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

I have a python program that runs through the command line with input arguments.

```
Python C:\Users\test.py -arg1 "Arg1" -arg2 "Arg2" -arg3 "arg3"
```

Now, I want to generate a .exe file for that program, so I compile it using py2exe. However, when I run this command it gives me this error:

```
At line:1 char:16
+ "test.exe" -arg1 "Arg1" -arg2 "Arg2" -arg3 "arg3" -arg4 ...
+ ~~~
Unexpected token '-arg1 in expression or statement.
```

I tried other commands such as:

```
 start C:\Users\test.exe -arg1 "Arg1" -arg2 "Arg2" -arg3 "arg3"
```

But I received this error:

```
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'arg1'.
At line:1 char:22
+ start "test.exe" -arg1 "Arg1" -arg2 "Arg2" --arg1 "Arg2"...
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

The code to parse the parameters is:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=' System')

parser.add_argument("-arg1", "--arg1", type=str, required=True, help='arg1 datat')
parser.add_argument("-arg2", "--arg2", type=str, required=True, help='arg2 data')
parser.add_argument("-arg3", "--arg3", type=str, required=True, help='arg3 data')

args = parser.parse_args()

x = args.arg1
y = args.arg2
z = args.arg2

print ("1st arg " ,x)
print ("2nd arg " ,y)
print ("3rd arg " ,z)
```

-Can anyone please help me with how to run the .exe file through the command line with passing arguments?

Comment: How are you parsing the parameter in your python file? It is impossible to help you without seeing at least that part.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I added the part you requested, please check it